# Pull rows for condition: date greater than 10/31/2013

Tags: excel, vba

I want to fetch all rows if date is greater than 10/31/2013.

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To a

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value > "10/31/2013" Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

My code works if I use date = 10/31/2013.

My date column also has null values.

Snapshot of data
[image: Here is the snapshot of data]

Comment: We don't have any of your data. How are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: If you have dates  formatted as dates on your sheet, then you need to use dates in your code, not strings.

Comment: `Option Explicit` `Option Explicit` `Option Explicit`. Please add that to the top of your code. You have undeclared variables and this will show you exactly where

Comment: Yes to all of the above, but the reason your `>` is not working as you would expect is because you have provided a string (wrapped in `"`) in your comparison. If you want to compare dates, provide a date wrapped in `#` like this: `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value > #10/31/2013# Then...`

Comment: i HAVE TRIED #10/31/2013# BUT DID NOT WORK

Comment: `Did not work` is not a useful explanation when troubleshooting. Did your computer spontaneously combust? Did you get an error? Did nothing happen at all? Did the wrong thing get copied?

Comment: @urdearboy: Thanks. i did. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562265/add-one-or-more-columns-while-copying-data-data-from-sheet1-and-pasting-data-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly qualifying your objects with a sheet which could very well be the issue. I adapted your code to properly qualify **all** objects & this will also be much faster since it will only copy/paste outside of the loop once.

For instance, say you have 500 rows that meet your criteria ( `Range > Date`). This means you will have 500 instances of rows being copied and pasted over and over inside your loop. The below method will only have one instance of copy/paste and is independent of how many rows meet your criteria. The more rows to be copied, the more you will benefit from this solution.

Another possible solution is to just simply filter by your criteria and copy/paste the visible cells only

---

Updated for more criteria added in comments - tested and working fine on my end

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, MyUnion As Range, LRow As Long

For i = 2 To ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If ws.Range("G" & i) > #10/31/2013# Or ws.Range("AA" & i) = "Investigate" Or ws.Range("AA" & i) = "Leave Open" Then
        If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set MyUnion = Union(MyUnion, ws.Range("G" & i))
        Else
            Set MyUnion = ws.Range("G" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        MyUnion.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & LRow)
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

---

*Before & After*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I also want to insert few columns in the beginning in Sheet2 when Macro copy data from Sheet 1 based on criteria that you helped me last time as mentioned in the above code.

Comment: That is off topic here. If questions were allowed to continuously evolve,  this site would never have a final answer. You need to post a new question as this is not what the original question was

Answer (score 1):

Dates are numeric values.  Use `#` instead of `"` when working with dates.

Selecting or activating ranges should be avoided watch [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim r As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For r = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If .Cells(r, 7).Value > #10/31/2013# Then
                .Rows(r).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `>` comparison is not working as you would expect is because you have provided a string (wrapped in `"`) in your comparison. If you want to compare dates, provide a date wrapped in `#` like this:

```
If CDate(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value) > #10/31/2013# Then
```

Note that I've also ensured the value in your cell is converted to a Date datatype by using `CDate`

Some additional comments, not related directly to your question:

You use `.select` and `.activate` in your code, but it is a much better practice to interact with the objects directly. For example, that whole `If` Block should be more like this:

```
If CDate(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value) > #10/31/2013# Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Paste
End If
```

Comment: I did convert to date column as date data type but after using your code i am getting no result in sheet2. I also added a data snapshot for the reference in my post.